# MapPoint/MapSource API for Calculating Distances

Tags: c#, api, mappoint, garmin

Good afternoon,

I need to calculate the pairwise distance between some 4000 points, the coordinates of which in WGS84 are known. Calculating the straight-line distances wasn't too hard, since I found [this](http://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gavaghan.org%2Fblog%2Ffree-source-code%2Fgeodesy-library-vincentys-formula%2F&ei=9LDvTPjZOsiAhQej7O2WDA&usg=AFQjCNFLL9H6MH_2BHCHWg-WIAlUAHKGjA&sig2=YuhYIPOaS9x-aBI1ufaRrg) C# library, but now I am interested in the shortest distance through roads instead of straight-line.

Using Google API or VIA Michelin is not a good option since they only allow between 1000-2500 calls and this would require almost 8 million... Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to do this in an offline fashing using Microsoft MapPoint 2009 / Garmin MapSource?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Winwaed actually has a tool for doing this, he is too modest to tell you :-)

See www.mapping-tools.com.

Otherwise, to program yourself, I recommend doing an Excel VBA macro, it is easy and intuitive to work with data.

See http://www.mp2kmag.com/excel/

There are also lot of instructive examples in the MapForums.com downloads section ($19.95).

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with MapPoint. MapPoint's API uses COM, so you will need COM interop. Works fine - I have three commercial products that use C# and MapPoint.

2009 has now been superseded by 2010, and 2011 is expected soon. of course the latest version will have the most uptodate road database.

Speed might be an issue, expect 8 million routes to take a few days on a single core machine with one processing thread.